# Find asymptotic solution of the PDE $u_{tt} + u_{ttxxxx} + u_{xxxx} = 0$, $u(0,x)=f(x)$, $u_{t} (0,x) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, asymptotics

We're looking to find an expression for the asymptotic behaviour of the bounded solution of the inital value PDE
$$u_{tt} + u_{ttxxxx} + u_{xxxx} = 0,$$
$u(0,x)=f(x)$, $u_{t} (0,x) = 0$, where $f,f',f'',f''',f''''$ are $L_{1}$ functions. Using fourier method we found a solution that can be written as:

$$u(t,x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(k) e^{ikx} \cosh(t \sqrt{ \frac{k^2}{1+k^4} }) dk,$$

Where $\hat{f}$ is the fourier transform of $f$. Now we'd like to use something like stationary phase or Laplace's method but the behaviour of $cosh$ as $t\to \infty$ doesn't really allow it, so any hint in the right direction as to how to tackle this would be very helpful.